# Magento crashed after adding new website

Tags: magento

I already have a Magento site running, & was trying to create a new website from within this installation. I added a code name of 'tb_new' and hit save. And my live site has crashed. It may be that Magneto does not like the new code name with an _.

UPDATE: On checking the error logs, it seems the problem is because the initial installation of Magento is under a specific user on my server, whereas the live site is running under a different user. Here's the error:

> a:4:{i:0;s:96:"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'tomharris'@'64.111.114.232' >(using password: YES)";i:1;s:2672:"#0 >/home/anotheruser/domainname.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): >Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()

How best do I quickly get my site running?

Comment: Have you look this thread http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8954/

Comment: Thanks but this is not helping.

Comment: First of all, adding an underscore in the code of a new website/store. Secondly I think you are having database issues. Somehow (if it isn't defined in the local.xml), your Magento is trying to connect to MySQL using the tomharris username from the IP 64.111.114.232. Have you looked at your config.xml , emptied the var/cache directory of Magento?